# Multiple line plots will not have same style in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple lines in the same figure with pyplot. The problem is that if I plot multiple lines, the formatting (linestyle, color) of the last plot overrides previous formatting. In addition, if I plot two lines in two different commands, the lines join connect (see figure [image: Capture]).

In the code xdata/ydata are np.arrays on the form:

```
[1, 2, 3,...]
```

The following code works without error messages, but the unwanted outcome:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(xdata, ydata,'-r')
ax.plot(xdata2, ydata2,'-b')
ax.plot((0),(0),'o',markersize=15, markerfacecoloralt='tab:red')
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

The goal is to get different line and marker styles on all three lines.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a weird bug;

The xdata2/ydata2 arrays had been appended (np.extend) to xdata/ydata arrays. Problem fixed!